# Bulk loading of languages in babel

Tags: babel

Assume that we have stored some language names in macros, e.g., `\csname lang1\endcsname{language_name_1}`, ..., `\csname lang<N>\endcsname{language_name_<N>}`, where `<N>` is some known smaller value.

Is there any way in plain TeX how to load all these language names to the `babel` package at once? Note please that I cannot load these languages directly by writing `\usepackage[{language_name_1},...,{language_name_<N>}]{babel}` since these names will be selected/defined by user.

I tried the following approach (with N=3 as an example) with no success...

```
\documentclass{article}

\expandafter\def\csname lang1\endcsname{english}
\expandafter\def\csname lang2\endcsname{german}
\expandafter\def\csname lang3\endcsname{polish}

\newcount\tmp
\tmp=1
\def\languages{%
  \loop\ifnum 3<\tmp
  \else
    \csname lang\the\tmp\endcsname
    \ifnum\tmp=3\relax\else,\fi
    \advance\tmp by 1\relax
  \repeat}

\usepackage[%
  \csname lang1\endcsname,
  \csname lang2\endcsname,
  \csname lang3\endcsname]{babel}

% \usepackage[\languages]{babel}   % This is what I want.

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}

\expandafter\def\csname lang1\endcsname{english}
\expandafter\def\csname lang2\endcsname{german}
\expandafter\def\csname lang3\endcsname{polish}

\newcount\tmp
\def\makelanguages#1{%
\edef\languages{\csname lang1\endcsname}%
\tmp=2%
\loop\ifnum \tmp<\the\numexpr#1+1\relax
   \edef\languages{\languages,\csname lang\the\tmp\endcsname} 
    \advance\tmp by 1\relax
  \repeat}
\makelanguages3 

\usepackage[\languages]{babel}   % This is what I want.

\begin{document}
I have loaded \languages.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your instructive answer. Now, I see what is the problem.